# "Improper alphabetic constant" error when input standalone subfile

Tags: xetex, standalone, ctex

Upgrade to TexLive2020 recently, and get "Improper alphabetic constant" error when `\input` a subfile with the `standalone` pkg. There's no problem if the subfile contents are directly put in the main file. There seems also no problem if the subfile is regular without `\begin{document}...\end{document}`.

The file compiled fine with old TexLive2019. It seems if I change the class to `article`, it goes fine. But I write in Chinese, the `ctexart` class is much more convenient. Please help.

Here's a MWE.
Main file:

```
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
\documentclass{ctexart}

\usepackage{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \input{G105}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
        \coordinate (A) at (1,1);
        \fill[gray] (O) |- (A) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Subfile: G105.tex

```
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
\documentclass[class=ctexart]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (A) at (1,1);
    \fill[gray] (O) |- (A) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Your test document compiles fine if I compile it under MacTeX2020/XeLaTeX *and* comment out (or simply delete) the instructions `\documentclass[class=ctexart]{standalone}`, `\usepackage{tikz}`, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. What are you trying to achieve by including these instructions and, in effect, feeding not one but two `\documentclass` directives to (Xe)LaTeX?

Comment: I think it's the purpose of ```standalone``` pkg. You can compile the subfile alone and preview the result. If everything is fine, then simply put it in the main file with ```\input```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a similar problem as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/568498/2388 but here with standalone and not subfiles.

By emptying the hook before loading the file you can avoid the problem (I had to use the fandol fontset, as the default errors for me):

```
\documentclass[fontset=fandol]{ctexart}

\usepackage{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
%\ShowHook{env/document/before}
\RemoveFromHook{env/document/before}[xeCJK] 
    \input{G105}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
        \coordinate (A) at (1,1);
        \fill[gray] (O) |- (A) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, works like magic. I can live with adding a single line in the main file while waiting for the bug fixed.

Comment: Well simply waiting will perhaps not help. You will have to report it somewhere.

Comment: Someone has reported the bug on GitHub [link](https://github.com/CTeX-org/forum/issues/186). Hopefully the authors of `CTeX` will notice it.